# TkMessageBox for user response

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

Is tkMessageBox able to ask a question that will allow user response in text form.  I have tried messagebox.askquestion() which only gives yes no and I have also tried messagebox.showinfo()

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want `Entry` widget e.g., see [the very first example in this tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `tkSimpleDialog.askstring()` function:

```
try: # Python 2
    from Tkinter import Tk
    from tkSimpleDialog import askstring
except ImportError: # Python 3
    from tkinter import Tk
    from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring

root = Tk()
root.withdraw() # hide main window

text = askstring("Title", "Prompt?")
print("Got: " + text)
```

Answer (score 1):

tkMessageBox can't do things like this. The website url I put below this post thoroughly explains this to you. Alternatively, turtle.textinput(title,prompt) (accessible through the turtle module) is certainly capable of doing such things.

http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/tkMessageBox.html

Comment: thank you so much! is there any way I could use the turtle command without opening up the turtle graphics window.

Comment: @user3133761: `turtle.textinput()` uses [`simpledialog.askstring()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20810780/4279) internally.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I didn't actually state the url in the post. Let me fix that...